# Node JS Express routing not handling / corrrectly

Tags: node.js, express, routes

I use the express Router in code as below.

The first definition accepts localhost:3000/tests which is correct.
The first definition also accepts localhost:3000/tests/ which seems incorrect.

When this second URL is accepted here, it results in my generating HTML that has incorrect relative URLs (e.g.  becomes /tests/hello rather than the desired /hello when the second URL is accepted).   Why is this happening?  Should I be doing something to prevent URLs with trailing slashes from matching?   If it has to accept both, how to I generate relative URLs that will be correct in both cases?

```
//tests.js:

const router = express.Router();

// accepts /tests AND /tests/
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 });

// accepts /tests/new AND /tests/new/
router.get('/new', function(req, res, next) {
 });

//app.js

var tests = require('./routes/tests');
app.use('/tests', tests);
```

All the node.js example code I look at uses routes like "/" and "/foo" so I'm not sure where I am going wrong.

Additional Edit:

When creating a relative URL it builds off the incoming URL.  So if a route handler accepts both /tests and /tests/ then all the relative URLs that get built will resolve to different paths because that last slash has a big effect on the formation of the concrete path.    I should add that in my deployed environment this app is forwarded to by apache using proxys so the full URLs to the node pages have a context like example.com/myapp/tests   .  The path in my devleopment environment would be different (e.g. localhost:3000/tests)

I use relative URLs in a couple places.

1. In the route handler I might do a res.redirect("foo").   So if the
   incoming URL is example.com/myapp/tests/ this would result in redirecting to the URL example.com/myapp/tests/foo, but if the incoming URL is example.com/myapp/tests this would result in redirecting to example.com/myapp/foo.   I am desiring this second one, not the first.
2. In an HTML page that I generate (rendered with EJS) there are includes of CSS and HTML forms, links, buttons.   So something like this CSS include resolves incorrectly if the incoming URL has a trailing slash

   link href = "stylesheets/my.css" rel = "stylesheet">

The paths to these things are all relative to the current page.  But if the location box of the browser is showing that page as example.com/myapp/tests/ 
I get a different URL than if it is example.com/myapp/tests  . In the former case, the CSS isn't found because its looking for it in /tests/stylessheets/my.css rather than in /stylesheets/my.css.  Similarly the other relative URLS resolve differently because this page can effectively be generated with two different incoming URLs.

Comment: I use absolute paths such as `/tests/hello` throughout my app without any problem why do you need relative ones? Can you possibly show where you have a problem with relative path?

Answer (score 0):

URLs with nothing after the trailing slash is the same as URL without the trailing slash. For example,  `/tests/new` is same as `/tests/new/`

From your code, the `tests.js` contains routes which won't do anything if your `app` isn't using it.

From your code, you use it for `/tests` which means that for `/tests` it will use routes defined in `tests.js`. This means that every route defined in the `tests.js` file will be appended after `/tests` because of:

```
app.use("/tests", tests);
```

If you want the /new route separately, you can do the following.

1. Define `/new` route in other file, and do `app.use("/", newRoute);`
2. Define the route there itself. (Though I don't suggest this as it will clutter your code)

Comment: My app isn't using a route like /tests/,  but if someone enters that URL by hand into the location box, the request gets sent in and my handler receives it and processes it and messes up the relative URLs.  I have other js files for other routes beside tests.   In the example, my desire is to process the route /tests/new    inside tests.js not somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:  You are routing everything through `tests` with this line:

```
.use("/tests", tests);
```

`Use` defines middleware which means that all your routes pass through it.